# Inserting from single table into multiple tables with auto id FK

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys, sql-insert

Not sure if the title help make it even a little clearer.
I am trying to import a log archive in excel files into a new system. The old data put everything into a single table.
In the new system these data are split into multiple tables with FK referencing a master log table's auto ID field.

```
old table: excel_log
| id | timestamp | person | event | sub_event | subject | subj_class | ... |

new tables : master_log
| id | timestamp | person | .... |

new tables : log_ext1
| id | mlog_id | subject | subject_class | ... |

new tables : log_ext2
| id | mlog_id | event_type | sub_event | event_param |
```

I added auxilary field `el_id` in `master_log`.
Inserted the `excel_table.id` altogether into the `master_log`.

```
alter table master_log add el_id int
insert into master_log (id, timestamp, person, ..., el_id )
select timestamp, person, ..., id
from excel_table
```

Then insert reset of fields in excel_table joing the `master_log` by `el_id` to find the generated mlog_id

```
insert into log_ext1 (mlog_id, ...)
select ml.id, el.subject, el....
from excel_table el left join master_log ml on el.id = ml.el_id
```

This is simple but also intrusive, since I have to alter the tables. 
I wonder what is nicer way in SQL Server to do `insert` with auto FKs ?

Comment: Assuming that a single log would only ever occupy a single record, I don't even see the point of breaking up the tables this way, not unless one log is so much data that it really can't fit into a single record.

Comment: The mast-log & log-exts are of one-many relationship. same timestamp multiple evts/subjs etc, there is no way to reliably rebuild that from excel log. I just stuff them in so the requested stats show up correctly in reports. (There're other irrelevant details but I just want to know how gurus handle the auto id FKs in INSERT :-)

Comment: Don't use auto id fields. Use original excel_log.id values. You can change column type to identity and reseed it after you have imported the data.